# Loop to send one email to a fixed number of addresses from a list until end of list. Nested range loops vs array

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel sheet with about 200 e-mail addresses in a column.

I'm trying to create an email with a standard recipient in the "to" field, and loop through those 200 addresses and put a fixed number of addresses in the "bcc" field and then create another mail with the next following fixed number of addresses, and so on until I have reached the end of the list.

I modified the following code I found online to send individual mails:

```vb
Sub BulkMail()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Activate
'Creating references to Application and MailItem Objects of Outlook
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

'Creating variable to hold values of different items of mail
Dim sendTo, subj, atchmnt, msg, ccTo, bccTo As String

Dim lstRow As Long

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Getting last row of containing email id in column 5.
lstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

'Variable to hold all email ids

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("E2:E" & lstRow, 20)

'initializing outlook object to access its features
Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
On Error GoTo cleanup 'to handle any error during creation of object.

'Loop to iterate through each row, hold data in of email in variables and send
'mail to each email id.

For Each cell In rng
    sendTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2
    subj = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value2 & "-MS"
    msg = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value2
    atchmnt = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value2
    ccTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value2
    bccTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value2

    On Error Resume Next 'to hand any error during creation of below object
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'Writing and sending mail in new mail
    With outMail
        .To = sendTo
        .BCC = bccTo
        .Body = "Hi this is a test"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Attachments.Add atchmnt
        .Send 'this send mail without any notification. If you want see mail
              'before send, use .Display method.
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0 'To clean any error captured earlier
    Set outMail = Nothing 'nullifying outmail object for next mail
 Next cell 'loop ends

cleanup: 'freeing all objects created
        Set outApp = Nothing
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

My searches to see if I can modify the step size didn't provide me with anything that seemed useful.

I understand that my range is set from the value in the second row until the last value found in a cell in (in this case) column E.

I essentially don't want to use `For Each cell In rng` but something like `For every 20 cells In rng` (the last one obviously doesn't work, but it might be a useful pseudo code example).

I've read that an array might be more useful, and from what I understood I could potentially store ranges of values in multiple arrays and then loop through the array. I want to learn to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the following piece of code:

```
For Each cell In rng
    sendTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2
    subj = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value2 & "-MS"
    msg = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value2
    atchmnt = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value2
    ccTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value2
    bccTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value2

    On Error Resume Next 'to hand any error during creation of below object
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'Writing and sending mail in new mail
    With outMail
        .To = sendTo
        .BCC = bccTo
        .Body = "Hi this is a test"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Attachments.Add atchmnt
        .Send 'this send mail without any notification. If you want see mail
              'before send, use .Display method.
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0 'To clean any error captured earlier
    Set outMail = Nothing 'nullifying outmail object for next mail
 Next cell 'loop ends
```

First of all, there is no need to create a new mail item object for each row in the worksheet. So, you need to create a mail item out of the loop:

```
Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(0)
sendTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 0).Value2
subj = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value2 & "-MS"
msg = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value2
atchmnt = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value2

Set recipients = outMail.Recipients

For Each cell In rng
    ccTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value2
    bccTo = Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 4).Value2
    
        
        recipientTo = recipients.Add(ccTo)
        recipientTo.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo
       
        recipientBCC = recipients.Add(bccTo)
        recipientBCC.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC
        
 Next cell 'loop ends
    
    recipients.ResolveAll()
    
.Body = "Hi this is a test"
.Subject = "Test"
.Attachments.Add atchmnt
.Send 'this send mail without any notification. If you want see mail

Set outMail = Nothing 'nullifying outmail object for next mail
```

Use the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Recipients) property of the `MailItem` class for adding recipients which contains a collection of `Recipient` objects for an Outlook item. Use the Add method to create a new Recipient object and add it to the Recipients object. The Type property of a new `Recipient` object is set to the default for the associated `AppointmentItem`, `JournalItem`, `MailItem`, or `TaskItem` object and must be reset to indicate another recipient type. The name can be a string that represents the display name, the alias, the full SMTP email address, or the mobile phone number of the recipient. A good practice is to use the SMTP email address for a mail message.

Read more about that in the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article.